# Can I play on a PS3 on a laptop using a HDMI cabel so I can use the laptop's monitor

Tags: laptop, ps3

Can I play on a PS3 on a laptop using a HDMI cable so I can use the laptop's monitor

Answer (score 1):

No.

The HDMI port on most laptops are for output from the graphics card only.

It may be possible if you find a USB tv card with HDMI in or a converter of some sort (HDMI > scart etc).

I have not yet seen a HDMI based tv card though.

Comment: I think that the TV card might introduce a delay that would make it unsuitable for gaming.

Comment: I used to play Dreamcast through a bog standard tv card using RF cable and there was no noticeable delay, so I do not think this would be a problem.